# Is there a reason findContours is giving me an error even though it shouldn't?

Tags: python, opencv

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     `1 im = image_list[4]
      2 ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,0)
----> 3 image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh , cv2.RETR_TREE , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
      4 image = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
      5`

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different versions of OpenCV return different numbers of items from cv2.findContours.

OpenCV 4 and OpenCV 2 have similar behavior returning two items, whereas OpenCV 3 returns three items.

Your version apparently only wants 2 items. So try

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh , cv2.RETR_TREE , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

or if you want something version independent, then if you need the hierarchy use

```
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hierarchy = contours[1] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[2]
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
```

or if you just want the contours simply

```
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
```